# Surface Arc Touch Mouse not working with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, mouse, bluetooth

After browsing for a while I found that there was an issue with 14.04 and the way that the Arc Touch mouse transmits its signal. This was meant to have been fixed in Bluez 5 but the case still exists that it connects but the mouse isn't functional.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I currently have the same problem and I don't think there's a clear fix to this issue.
Did you install bluez 5? Ubuntu currently ships with bluez 4.
I've tried to install newest bluez via ppa but it broke my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally been able to solve this issue.

1. Grab the bluez packages named *5.23-1ubuntu1~mtrudel1* and *indicator-bluetooth* from the [following PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/transitions).
2. You need to modify the bluez package and remove the dependencies *init-system-helpers* and *lsb-base*, otherwise you're going to have some dependency issues when you perform a system update.
3. Manually install that modified package and the *indicator-bluetooth*.
4. Download and install the 2.0.1 version of blueman from [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=blueman).
5. Reboot and you should see the new bluetooth indicator icon in the panel. Open it up and setup your Arc Touch mouse. It should pair and connect without any problem.

To solve some auto reconnect issues I was having, I had to install the 14.04.3 LTS point release that just came out.

Answer (score -1):

I followed what Ali said. It is not so trivial to modify the packages.

I have done this for the 64bits (AMD64) Ubuntu 14.04 and it works like a charm.

Here is an archive with a setup.sh that allow to do this.

[UPDATE FOR MICROSOFT ARC TOUCH MOUSE ON UBUNTU 14.04 64BITS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvavocnhzilg3bi/UPDATE_14.04_FOR_ARC_TOUCH_64bits.tar.gz?dl=0)

Uncompress it, then

sudo ./setup.sh