# How to connect Microsoft Arc Touch Bluetooth Mouse in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and I am having problems to connect my Arc Touch Bluetooth Mouse to my Dell laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.

I read the answers to this question: [Microsoft Arc Touch Bluetooth Mouse not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891470/microsoft-arc-touch-bluetooth-mouse-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04), and found that typing in command line:

```
$ sudo btmgmt le on
```

... makes the mouse discoverable and makes it possible to pair and connect and to use it properly.

However, if I close and reopen the laptop, the mouse does not connect anymore, I need to retype the command in the terminal again.

Any ideas of how can I make this setting permanent? Thanks!